# Boostrap grid height and placing row with height: auto

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am doing a simple page with a bootstrap grid and I am having some problems with placing the middle row occupying the full height in the middle.

These are the 3 rows: [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTIPY.png)

I want to place the row with the logo in the middle, but I am having problems with it. I placed `height: 100%;`, `height: auto;`. I even placed the container height to 100% and auto and nothing works!

I think there is a concept about bootstrap heigh that I am missing, because its the heigh that I have problems

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-2">
      <img id="menuIcon" (click)="toggleRightSidenav()" onmouseover="this.src='../../../assets/Images/generic/menuIcon_hover.png'" src="/assets/Images/generic/menuIcon.png" onmouseout="this.src='/assets/Images/generic/menuIcon.png'">
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-8">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-2">
    <img id="helpIcon" routerLink="/guide" onmouseover="this.src='../../../assets/Images/home/helpIconHover.png'" src="/assets/Images/home/helpIcon.png" onmouseout="this.src='/assets/Images/home/helpIcon.png'">
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="row row align-items-center mh-100" >
    <div class= "col-md-12">
      <img id="logo" src="/assets/Images/home/Logo.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-around fixed-bottom">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
       <img id="addButton"  routerLink="/addPlayer" onmouseover="this.src='../../../assets/Images/generic/addIcon_hover.png'" src="../../../assets/Images/generic/addIcon.png" onmouseout="this.src='/assets/Images/generic/addIcon.png'" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
      <p>Players Waiting:  {{playerWaiting}} </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
      <p>Listed Players: {{playersListed}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
      <img id="searchButton" routerLink="/search" onmouseover="this.src='../../../assets/Images/generic/searchIcon_hover.png'" src="../../../assets/Images/generic/searchIcon.png" onmouseout="this.src='/assets/Images/generic/searchIcon.png'" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div{
  border: yellow 1px solid;
}

#menuIcon{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#helpIcon{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#addButton{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 127px;
}
#searchButton{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 127px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/Xd0xi5hFNc

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle for your issue?

Comment: I will create one

Comment: I updated with code editor

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.

1. To be able to fill several rows, you'd need a height for the container div.

**Current HTML**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
```

**Update as**

```
 <div class="container-fluid d-flex vh-100 flex-column">
```

2. Now you can easily make your middle div fill the remaining gap by adding a `fill-height` class.

**Current HTML**

```
<div class="row row align-items-center mh-100" >
```

**Update as**

```
<div class="row row align-items-center fill-height">
```

**Add this to your css**

```
.fill-height {
   flex: 1;
}

.fixed-bottom {
     position: sticky;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/780gfsde/2/)**

Comment: Glad to help ;)